# Why is platinum an excellent catalyst in comparison with similar metals?

Tags: metal, transition-metals, catalysis

What is special about platinum structure which actively participate in catalytic reactions while similar metals with similar atomic structures cannot.

Comment: Indeed, similar metals with similar structures ($\ce{Pd,\;Ir}$) are just about as good in many catalytic reactions, so $\ce{Pt}$ is not all that exceptional.

Comment: @IvanNeretin Righto. The whole cluster of them has a name: [Platinum group metals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Platinum_group)